# Show Aler me only when click Actions menu in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

how to show only alert me option to the user using javascript or some other way in sharepoint 2007. i want to hide all other options on the actions menu

Answer (score 1):

var doc = document.getElementsByTagName('ie:menuitem'); 
 for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++)
  {
    itm = doc[i];
    if (itm.id.match('ViewRSS')!=null || itm.id.match('OpenInExplorer')!=null || itm.id.match('EditInGridButton')!=null || itm.id.match('OfflineButton')!=null || itm.id.match('ExportToSpreadsheet')!=null)
      { itm.hidden=true; }
  }

For just one library use SharePoint Designer add this to the bottom of the allitems.aspx for that library. The best place is just before the end tag of the "PlaceHolderMain" placeholder tag.

Comment: can't we use a content editor web part and with using javascript hide all the menuitems in the Actions menu other than Alert Me menuitem

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/c83159a3-1e10-4a37-aa0b-541658162f0f) has some options to hide Alert Me. You can use the same method to hide other menu items. Hope the options should be hiden for everyone.